Need to extract the value from 4th nested object from Get response in Postman
This is the response I get from the GET request
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "660e712d000081efd50a23485963f7b6d",
      "name": "test1",
      "objCode": "OPTASK",
      "enteredBy": {
        "ID": "5ede31210141630d03517f6ec308a3c0",
        "name": "Priyanka Haridas",
        "objCode": "USER"
      },
      "resolvingObjID": null,
      "DE:Automate Assignment": "5ede31210141630d03517f6ec308a3c0",
      "DE:Story Points": "2",
      "DE:SM - What are you updating ?": "SM - Large - XL Effeort - Trnaslations | PLM Approval | ASAP",
      "parameterValues": {
        "DE:VSN - Does your request contain changes to text?": "No",
        "DE:SM - Region 2 Countries": [
          "UK/Ireland",
          "Portugal",
          "Sweden",
          "Germany",
          "Poland"
        ],
        "DE:VSN - Please explain the change you are making.": "This is a test",
        "DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions": "{\"objCode\":\"USER\",\"name\":\"Priyanka Haridas\",\"ID\":\"5ede31210141630d03517f6ec308a3c0\"}",
        "DE:SM - Additional/back-up contact for request questions": {
          "objCode": "USER",
          "name": "Priyanka Haridas",
          "ID": "5ede31210141630d03517f6ec308a3c0"
        },
        "DE:SM - Regions in Scope": [
          "Region 3",
          "Region 1",
          "Region 4",
          "Region 2"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}


I need to extract the value of ID from
"DE:SM - Additional/back-up contact for request questions": "{"objCode":"USER","name":"Priyanka Haridas","ID":"5ede31210141630d03517f6ec308a3c0"}"
I have tried several methods, but none seem to be working.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

This script can extract ID.
const object = JSON.parse(jsonData.data[0].parameterValues['DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions']);
console.log(object.ID)

Two Items can  address your problem
#1 "Key name in JSON contains a space"
"parameterValues": {
    "DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions": value
}

This format can access a value
parameterValues['key name with space']
parameterValues['DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions']

let values = { 
    "DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions": "{\"objCode\":\"USER\",\"name\":\"Priyanka Haridas\",\"ID\":\"5ede31210141630d03517f6ec308a3c0\"}"
};

console.log(values['DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions']);

Result

#2 Value includes \"
You need to convert from JSON string to JSON Object by JSON.parse()
If you use JSON.parse() on this string, you will convert it into a JavaScript object. Here's what would happen:
Starting with the JSON string.
Using JSON.parse() to convert it to a JavaScript object.
JSON.parse() is used to convert a JSON string into a JavaScript object. This method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.
"{\"objCode\":\"USER\",\"name\":\"Priyanka Haridas\",\"ID\":\"5ede31210141630d03517f6ec308a3c0\"}"

JSON.parse(values)
let values = { 
    "DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions": "{\"objCode\":\"USER\",\"name\":\"Priyanka Haridas\",\"ID\":\"5ede31210141630d03517f6ec308a3c0\"}"
};

const data1 = values['DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions']
console.log("data1.ID: " + data1.ID);

const data2 = JSON.parse(values['DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions'])
console.log("data2.ID: " + data2.ID);

Result

Full Demo by Postman
In Tests tab
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData.data[0].parameterValues['DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions']);
const object = JSON.parse(jsonData.data[0].parameterValues['DE:SM - Primary contact for request questions']);
console.log(object.ID)


